# 2 methods but yet couldn't solve. python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

**I have tried:**

First, I did a code like this

```
elif a_options == 2:
        a_update=raw_input("select a word to update:")
        a_renew_word = raw_input("the new word")
        if a_update in empt_list:
            empt_list[a_update]=a_renew_word
        else:
            print "sorry"
        # print a_list[a_options-1]
```

**got an error:**

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

**Also tried:**

```
elif a_options == 2:
    a_update=raw_input("select a word to update:")
    a_renew_word = raw_input("the new word")
    if a_update in empt_list:
        empt_list.index(a_update)=a_renew_word
    else:
        print "sorry"
```

**Another Error**

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

here you go with the complete code, i tried to do with lists, cuz i thought it suits the best, but if there is any other method i will accept it. any idea, or find where is the prob i tried to search but i couldnt find any solution, here i am here to ask you.

```
print "hello, welcome to"
a_list=["1. Add a new word","2. Update and existing word","3. Detele and existing word","4. Display a words definition"]
zero=0
empt_list=[]
empt_list_meaning=[]
def list_game():
    for i in a_list:
        print i
    a_options=input("Please select one of these options: ")
    if a_options== 1:
        a_newword=raw_input("What word you want to add? ")
        empt_list.append(a_newword)
        a_newword_meaning=raw_input("add the meaning of the word")
        empt_list_meaning.append(a_newword_meaning)
        # print a_list[a_options-1]
        print empt_list,a_newword,"added correctly"

    elif a_options == 2:
        a_update=raw_input("select a word to update:")
        a_renew_word = raw_input("the new word")
        if a_update in empt_list:
            empt_list.index(a_update)=a_renew_word
        else:
            print "sorry"
        # print a_list[a_options-1]

    elif a_options == 3:
        a_del_word=raw_input("selct the word you want to delete")
        for i in empt_list:
            if a_del_word in empt_list:
                empt_list.remove(a_del_word)
        # print a_list [a_options-1]


    elif a_options  == 4:
        for i in empt_list:
            print i
    print ("would you like to continue or exit?\n1.contine\n2.exit")
    now=input(">>> ")
    if now==1:
        list_game()
    else:
        print "arrivederchi"
list_game()
```

I don't know what else I can do, appreciate any kind of help.
thank you with respect umer selmani

Comment: It looks like you need the `index(a_update)` to get the index, e.g. `empt_list[empt_list.index(a_update)]=a_renew_word`

Comment: @AChampion, i will upload the whole code now and you can have a look on it.

Comment: @Nick i will upload the code now and you can have a look on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.index()` to find the position, then assign to the list at that position:

```
a_update=raw_input("select a word to update:")
a_renew_word = raw_input("the new word")
if a_update in empt_list:
    position = empt_list.index(a_update)
    empt_list[position] = a_renew_word
else:
    print "sorry"
```

This is the same thing that @AChampion suggested, but broken into two separate lines to make it a little clearer.